# Google App Engine Forward Request

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any way to forward an incoming request to GAE, kind of like a reverse proxy, to another server, but without urlfetch? URLFetch is very buggy, and during an attack, I run out of resources, and hence the server crashes.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the Python standard libraries urllib, urllib2 or httplib to make HTTP requests. When running in App Engine, **these libraries perform HTTP requests using App Engine's URL fetch service**, which runs on Google's scalable HTTP request infrastructure.

So whatever you use, it's all App Engine's URL Fetch service anyway. So I'd say no.

[Fetch Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do a forward or redirect. You can use a cname in your DNS to create an alias for you new address or a meta refresh in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.example.com/'" />
```

It all depends on your needs and the kind of request.